# Is it good practice to wrap related set of properties into its own struct/class?

Tags: swift, data-structures

Writing a User object in Swift, though my question relates to any strongly typed language. A User can have a bunch of links (FacebookProfile, InstagramProfile, etc). A few questions around this.

1. Is it good practice to wrap links in its own object?

```
    struct User {
       var firstName: string
       var lastName: string
       var email: string
       var links: Links
    }
```

```
    struct Links {
       var facebook: string
       var instagram: string
       var twitter: string 
    }
```

Or should they be loose? I know technically both ways are fine, but wondering if there is a recommended approach, in general--especially for readability.

```
struct User { 
   var firstName: string
   var lastName: string
   var email: string
   var facebookLink: string
   var twitterLink: string
   var instagramLink: string
}
```

2. In a scenario like this, should links be a collection/list? I figured it should not be a list because there is a fixed number of link options available, and not a growing number. Is my thinking right?
3. Is it good practice to place my networking methods inside the User object, like getUsers, getUser, updateUser?

I know these could be subjective, but I am trying to understand what the best practice around similar situations is. Would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very subjective, it depends on the calling site / usage of the `struct` `User`

## My personal preference:

1. Don't worry too much about `User` being separated as `Links`. For now keep it as one whole struct. If you see a need to break it you could look at different options.
2. If it is a fixed set of types of links, you could even look at enum with associated values. For now I would simply have them loosely as `URL?`
3. Is an instance of `User` going to be created by parsing data ? If so I would prefer to keep it just as value (struct) that I can pass around. I would prefer to keep networking services separate that would take an array of `User` objects to fetch / update at once.

## Note:

- I feel it would make sense to understand the purpose of User
- How parsing of `User` is done ? (`Codable` / initialising with a dictionary) ?
- Build things incrementally, don't over engineer, if you see a need to then do it otherwise wait till you see a need for it.